# Installing the ADT plugin in Eclipse kepler

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I installed Eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1 on windows 7 and I had configured the proxy, and I was trying to install the ADT plugin.
I used the following links one by one both by https and http

- https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

I followed the following steps:-

1. Run the eclipse.exe as administrator
2. Then help->Install New Software
3. Then entered the  the link  in **Work With** field
4. Then clicked **ADD** button
5. Then entered the **ADT** in the **NAME** field, and the link in the **Location** field
6. I was getting an error in which the Dialog box says

> Error Contacting Site
>   No software site found at
>   Do you wish to edit the location ?
>   Yes NO
>   
>   I also tried to use the ADT installation from a Zip file in this link 
>   http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html
>   but the **Android** option is not coming under the windows->preference

Comment: https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-eclipse-4.3